# Exclude SQL query results with multiple conditions - single table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I ran into a problem with a query I am using from another question that was previously asked. I did not want to add to that question, so I am just starting a new one. This scenario is with SQL Server 2008.

```
Order Number    Order Line    Package    Part Number    Size    Cost    Reviewed
   0001              1           1           A1          S      22.5      Yes
   0001              1           1           B2          M      33.1      Yes
   0001              1           1           C3          L      11.2      Yes
   0001              1           2           A1          XL     15.0      Yes
   0001              1           3           A2          M      12.0      Yes
   0001              2           1           D1          S      42.9      Yes
   0002              1           1           B4          L      72.5      No
   0002              1           2           A7         XXL     66.7      No
   0002              2           1           C1          XL     11.8      Yes
   0002              2           1           B1          S      22.3      Yes
   0003              1           1           A1          L      55.2      Yes
```

I would like to select Order Number, Order Line, and Package. I have to search by Part Number, Size, Cost, and if it was Reviewed. This table has around 30,000 orders, so there will be multiple results (which is what I want). I have to exclude results that have an Order Line where Package <> 1. In other words, I do not want an instance of an order line if it has a package <> 1. An order is split up into several rows, and each row can have multiple packages attached to it. Below is the query that works correctly.

```
SELECT
   ORDERNumber,
   ORDERLine,
   Package
FROM
   orders a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM orders AS b
                    WHERE a.ordernumber = b.ordernumber
                          AND a.orderline = b.orderline
                          AND b.Package <> 1)
GROUP BY
ORDERNumber,
   ORDERLine,
   Package
```

Here are the results of the above example query (which correctly meets my requirements)...

```
ORDERNUMBER     ORDERLINE     PACKAGE 
0001            2             1 
0002            2             1 
0003            1             1
```

The problem I am having occurs when I try to add multiple conditions. For example...

```
SELECT
   ORDERNumber,
   ORDERLine,
   Package
FROM
   orders a
WHERE (REVIEWED = 'Yes' AND SIZE = 'L') OR (REVIEWED = 'Yes' AND SIZE = 'S')
AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM orders AS b
                    WHERE a.ordernumber = b.ordernumber
                          AND a.orderline = b.orderline
                          AND b.Package <> 1)
GROUP BY
ORDERNumber,
   ORDERLine,
   Package
```

Gives me the following results (which does NOT meet my requirements)...

```
ORDERNUMBER     ORDERLINE     PACKAGE 
0001            1             1 
0001            2             1 
0002            2             1 
0003            1             1
```

Order number 0001, Order Line 1 is not valid because it has a 2 and 3 values for Package. It looks like there is something wrong with my order of conditions? I have tried playing around with these conditions, but I am not getting the results I want. I know this can be done with two separate queries and a UNION statement, but is there a way I can do multiple conditions with only one query for this scenario? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your query and add brackets between your `OR` arguments:

```
((REVIEWED = 'Yes' AND SIZE = 'L') OR (REVIEWED = 'Yes' AND SIZE = 'S'))
```

so full query looks like this:

```
SELECT
   ORDERNumber,
   ORDERLine,
   Package
FROM
   orders a
WHERE ((REVIEWED = 'Yes' AND SIZE = 'L') OR (REVIEWED = 'Yes' AND SIZE = 'S'))
      AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                       FROM orders AS b
                       WHERE a.ordernumber = b.ordernumber
                             AND a.orderline = b.orderline
                             AND b.Package <> 1)
GROUP BY
         ORDERNumber,
         ORDERLine,
         Package
```

because your original query it was first evaluated `(REVIEWED = 'Yes' AND SIZE = 'L')` and if it was not matched then `(REVIEWED = 'Yes' AND SIZE = 'S'))
      AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                       FROM orders AS b
                       WHERE a.ordernumber = b.ordernumber
                             AND a.orderline = b.orderline
                             AND b.Package <> 1)` was evaluated. As you can see your exists statement was linked with second check.

Comment: DOH! I tried everything BUT that. Rookie mistake. Then again, I am a rookie. Thanks @gzaxx. What if I wanted to add another exclusion - would I add it to the NOT EXISTS statement in the same manner? I am assuming so, I just haven't tried it yet.

Comment: No problem, glad I helped :). About your question I think it should work just fine :)